# REGEXP_EXTRACT after a pattern

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm really blind about regex. I want to extract after the word 'page='

```
page=course; uri=%2Fcourse
page=homepage
```

in this case it would be "course" and "homepage". I've tried

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(context, r"(?<=page=)+[a-zA-Z]*")
```

but it said ***"Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<"*** in Google BigQuery.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Google's [regex library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) doesn't support lookbehinds, but you can use a capture group to get [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to return that substring instead of the entire match:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(context, r"page=([a-zA-Z]+)")
```

Comment: Hi! thank you.. I've already tried it and it works!
anyway do you know how if I want to also include the word 'page=' so it would be 'page=course' or 'page=homepage'

Comment: @AnisaDaraputri just remove the `()` from the regex, then it will capture the entire string.

Comment: I see.. It worked! Okay I guess i somewhat understand the pattern now. thank you ^^